# How to use formSpy and isFormValid in the context of ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, validation, sinon

I was asked to do an exercise in interview, but then see in the testing code:

```
  it('check validation when the form is valid', () => {
    let formSpy = spy();
    const form = mount(<Form isFormValid={formSpy} />);
    form.find('.name').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Peter' } });
    
    form.find('.button').simulate('click');
    expect(formSpy.calledWith(true)).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Should I write my `<form>` or ReactJS in a certain way, so that the test can know whether the form is valid?

I have my own function named `validateForm()`, so how is the test able to see whether my form is valid, because my validation can say the name my be in "title case" and must be at least 2 characters long, but the test doesn't know what my code is for the validation. (I think the test might be in Sinon, although I am not entirely sure).

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do I reproduce a whole testing framework here? It is something I saw in an interview where they have a testing framework set up online. It wouldn't be possible to set up a testing framework on Stackoverflow